# How to get the third party app data in marketing cloud data extension or how to unlock the Import directory?

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

we can get the magento app data in marketing cloud using windscribe or filezilla, and FTP user of marketing cloud for that.

we can use the automation for that in this use the file drop and import file activity. But now i want to import other file in the same import file location but it was locked because its already used in one automation.

So, how can i import the magento  app data in marketing cloud or how can i unlock the import directory[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDy5z.png)

we will try it using filezilla to store the records but the import directory was locked and our magento data will stored into the import directory using windscribe. So , we can create new folder under the import directory but we can not get all data in data extension.